# Passive voice - have been studied?

Tags: voz-pasiva

If I want to say "these things have been studied" would I use passive voice, as in "se han estudiado?"

Comment: voz pasiva: > She had made many mistakes
> > My students would answer that question

Comment: @deborah, your answer does not make sense at all. To "how would I say this in Spanish" you answer with a couple of unrelated sentences _in English_!. Those sentences are not even in passive voice, as you claim.

Answer (score 7):

"Han sido estudiadas" is the true passive voice.

"Se han estudiado" is reflexive.

Answer (score 3):

Spanish allows to utilize two different types of passive sentences, so it would have been possible to make both of the next translations:

> Estas cosas han sido estudiadas.
>
> Se han estudiado esas cosas. (pasiva refleja)

The first option is normally chosen when the subject is important (*estas cosas*), while the second is used when is not, and is what happens what is stressed in your sentence.

Answer (score 2):

> Estas cosas han sido estudiadas.

As it's a plural form

Comment: So using ser is better here than the passive voice?

Comment: well really you can also use "Estas cosas se han estudiado". That depends, the one used in my answer is mostly used to says that something have been "fully" studied, in the past. This other way you means that it's something that it's still being studied. (sorry for my english)